# Jenkins "I'll fix the build" plugin

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

does anybody knows if there is a Jenkins /Hudson plugin that when the build is broken it allows you to set some status (like I'll fix it! ) so that other people in the team know that

- Somebody is working on the issue
- Who is working on the issue

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it's called Claim Plugin ([For more info read here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Claim+plugin))

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Catlight](https://catlight.io) build status notifier.

Engineer can click on "I will investigate", and the other team members will see that this build is being checked. The workflow is described in more details in [this article](http://blog.catlight.io/post/144836050563/build-investigations).

[image: Catlight build investigation]

Catlight is a desktop app that runs on Windows and OS X. It will also show the current status of the build in tray, and toaster notifications on changes of the status.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a bug-tracking/ticketing system, consider looking for a plugin that creates a ticket on the bug-tracker. Then your regular issue-resolution process can kick-in as soon as a build fails. For example a simple process would be

1. Manager assigns the ticket to a developer
2. Developer checks in the changes to trigger another build
3. Manager confirms the build is fixed and closes the ticket

For an example see the [plugin for mantis](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Mantis+Plugin)